# How to delay compilation of transcluded content

Tags: angularjs

When an Angular directive is defined with "transclude: true", the contents of the directive element gets removed from the element, compiled and held "in limbo" until someone injects it into the directive through either ng-Transclude or the transclude function.  It is sometimes undesirable to have all transcluded contents be compiled immediately before they get injected because sometimes they may actually never get injected at all.

For example, I have a Dialog directive that transcludes the contents into a Kendo UI window widget (the specific usage of this kendo widget is irrelevant).  I only want the contents of the Dialog directive compiled when the dialog is open.  Is there some way to delay the compilation of transcluded contents in Angular?

```
<dialog kendo-window-api="controller.kendoWindowApiThatHasAnOpenFunction">
    <!-- I don't want the following complex directive to get compiled until the dialog is opened in code behind -->
    <another-complex-directive>some content here</another-complex-directive>
</dialog>
```

I also tried to turn off transclusion altogether and manually compile the content HTML, but because transclusion has been turned off and because a template is used by my Dialog directive, the content HTML gets removed by Angular and I don't have access to it in the Dialog directive link function.  Any suggestions on how to work around this issue?